# Carregar função js automaticamente e para varias divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

O meu problema é o seguinte.

Eu possuo duas ou mais divs na minha pagina e quero chamar uma função automaticamente para elas ao carregar a pagina em questão. E ao mesmo tempo que eu chamar estas funções quero passar alguns parametros para que sejam tratados no js e retornado.

Vou tentar explicar de outra forma.

```
<div id="a" class="" teste('lala')>
    <span></span>
</div>

<div id="b" class="" teste('papa')>
    <span></span>
</div>

<div id="c" class="" teste('caca')>
    <span></span>
</div>

<div id="d" class="" teste('baba')>
    <span></span>
</div>


function teste (parametro){
    var parametro = parametro;

    /* Preciso neste momento pegar a div que esta chamando a função e atribuir o valor passado para a sua respectiva div. Isso é possível? */
}
```

Resumindo o que eu preciso que vocês me ajudem:
- Fazer com que a div chame a função ao carregar a pagina, eu queria usar o onLoad, mais ele só funciona para o body
- Reconhecer a div que esta chamando a função e atribuir o parametro em alguma filha dela (neste exemplo a span).

Lembrando que todo o js vai estar em um arquivo externo.

Quem poder me ajudar, agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que criar eventos para que tal coisa aconteça.

**Com Jquery:**

```
$('#a').ready(function() {
    teste('lala');
});

$('#b').ready(function() {
    teste('papa');
});

$('#c').ready(function() {
    teste('caca');
});

$('#d').ready(function() {
    teste('caca');
});

function teste (parametro){
    var parametro = parametro;
}
```

Obs: Caso tenha interface complexa ou com alto nível de conteúdo dinâmico, sugiro usar algum framework Javascript.

Comment: Seria conteudo dinamico mesmo. O que estou tentando fazer, é um countdown dinamico. A unica forma q encontrei foi por js ao php com ajax. Mais mesmo assim esta muito complicado.

Comment: Estou tendo problemas em chamar a função automaticamente para os N countdown na tela. A função do countdown eu consegui montar, esta linda dmais. Mais chamar esta função separadamente pra cada countdown na tela esta sendo o meu ponto fraco.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o onload em qualquer elemento no html [como pode ver](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)
mas não tem so este meio para isto.
Para pegar o elemento filho, primeiro você tem que saber qual o elemento

```
<div id="a" class="" onload="teste(this,'lala')">
<span></span>
</div>
<script>
function teste (elemento,parametro){
console.log(elemento,parametro);
//elemento é todas as propriedades do elemento que foi carregado
elemento.children[0].innerText = paramentro;//carregando o texto pelo parametro usado
 }
</script>
```

Mas como disse, tem meios melhores para fazer isto.

Comment: Qual seria o melhor meio de se fazer isso?